# How to fix image on Report.rdlc by giving path?

Tags: c#, report

I don't want save image in database. My application going to work on different shops i want show their logos on report.rdlc. For that i want to know, can i show image on report.rdlc by using path of image only? I tried to create parameter for Report.rdlc in ReportData but there is not any image Datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can:

1. Set image **Source** to **External**
2. Set image **Value** to an URL or file path
3. Set `EnableExternalImages=true` in your report code

You can also refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251715(v=vs.80).aspx for some additional info, but those steps above must be enough.